# How to filter an struct array type column in AWS Athena using SQL based on a parameter?

Tags: sql, struct

I have a column called `data_contents` in a table called `transactions`. The data type of that column is as follows:

```
array<struct<id:string,variant_id:string,quantity:string,
item_price:string,title:string,image:string,brand:string,url:string,type:string,category:string,
description:string>>
```

The table is in AWS Athena.

The other columns in this table are `application_id, event_name` etc.

I want to print any 20 records with their application_id and event_name, whose value of description is not null in the data_contents column of the transactions table.

How can I write the SQL for this scenario?

Comment: It is easier to get an answer here if you make an initial effort, and show where you are stuck. Readers prefer not to be asked to do the whole thing for a question author. Indeed, if you try it, you may figure it out for yourself, which is a good educational experience.